# How to integrate zo sdk with flutter windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop, zoom-sdk

I need to integrate zoom sdk with flutter windows app but the package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_sdk  only support android , ios and web

Does any body knows how i can build
Flutter windows app with zoom sdk ?!